# Widgets appear to be entirely missing from my device

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen

When I long press on the Home screen, I am offered a "Choose Wallpaper From" menu.  Everything I've looked at says I should be able to add Widgets here also, but nope.  Widgets are not automatically added when I install one, and I've been through the Settings pretty thoroughly without seeing a mention of Widgets.  What am I missing?

I have a Nexus 4 running 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-tapping on the home screen is how widgets used to be added in earlier Android versions, up to about 2.1. Some devices (such as Samsung ones) still offer the old way on the manufacturer's stock home screen: adding widgets is a feature offered by the launcher, so some third-party launchers may have yet different ways.

On the stock Android launcher, go to the app drawer (the list of all apps), and click **Widgets** at the top. Find the one you want (there are several pages), and long-tap it to pick it up, then drag and drop to the space you want on the home screen. You can drag to the left or right edge to change home screens. Once you've dropped it, you can drag the blue highlight to resize the widget (if it's resizable).

Comment: Thanks!  I amazed I didn't run across this detail.  I read pages claiming that the 4.4 process is the same as what you say is pre-Froyo.

Comment: @MatthewRead There's actually a good reason for that: some manufacturers' stock home screens still work that way. I've updated my answer to make that clearer.